# IRAN blocked tor network, THE NEW CHINA?

Tags: exit-relays, bridge, censorship

recently we noticed that Iran's government by using firewall or blocking tor exit nodes or .... has blocked access to websites hosted inside, no websites inside Iran is accessible via tor. we thought site owners take some steps against tor but we were wrong.

It's too odd if they installed firewall in the country's internet gateway, but take some steps for sure, is there anyway to resolve this, any Idea?

some websites for example:

https://mihanwebhost.com/
https://www.sheypoor.com/
https://divar.ir/s/tehran
http://tehran.ir/

Thanks

Comment: The only option right now is to try to limit yourself to exit nodes inside of Iran. If there aren't any, then it might be impossible to access them short of going there yourself.

Comment: I propose to change the title, because it sounds very much like discussing politics and opinions.

Comment: I was not going to make it sounds like politics discussion but, after gasoline increase in Iran for 200%, they blocked access to all sites hosted inside Iran using TOR. it's not done by websites admins but by government, while there is no threat for them. we desperately need to access divar.ir using TOR, for scraping. Thanks and my apologies if the topic is doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an obfuscator such as obfs4, and the corresponding bridges from [bridges.torproject.org](https://bridges.torproject.org/)

Comment: Thanks but I tried them all, no bridges, obfs4 or the like work. I have access to sites hosted abroad but not whose hosted inside IRAN.

Comment: He's asking for the opposite. He wants to access sites inside of Iran. Not access external sites from inside Iran.

Comment: Well, they are accessible from outside.. getting outside of Iranian IP space would be one solution.

Comment: If you mean to connect to TOR network using a VPN such as Windscribe that change the IP address of whole system, I tried it but does not work. I meant divar.ir is not still accessible in Tor browser.

Comment: I have not tried to access the sites through TOR but they are accessible without it. Using a VPN to get an exit point outside of Iran should let you browse them. Although I did not test, they may be filtering exit node IPs

Comment: we were using TOR for scraping divar.ir, I'm living in Iran, so there is no need to browse them using VPN or the like, after ... queries, they block the IP, so we were using TOR, and now none of websites hosted inside Iran is accessible using TOR. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like they are filtering TOR exit nodes. It is possible to continue doing that if you use proxies or VPNs. There are plenty free VPNs that would make it possible to scrape the mentioned pages.